# Has there been work on formal Semantics for linear algebra?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, type-systems, operational-semantics

Could I get some references on formal semantics for a calculus on linear algebra that helps you study matrix or tensor based programming languages? I am looking for anything that encompasses linear or multilinear algebra objects and operations as first class constructs.

I remember seeing something on it a while ago but I can't seem to find that paper or any other reference on the subject. If there is any specific terminology that would help me search for it better it would also be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to what kind of features you are looking for in this hypothetical language. Presumably, formal semantics of the operands simply correspond to the appropriate mathematical operation in (multi)-linear algebra.

Comment: As cody says, the question is a bit unfocussed. Most programming languages define linear algebra libraries, which lifts the  formal semantics of the base language to the linear algebra operations.